# backing up databases wordpress 3.1.2

Tags: database, wordpress, database-backups

I was wondering how to backup the databases of a site running on Wordpress v3.1.2 before updating to the most recent version of Wordpress.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: use cpanel or mysqldump via the command line

Comment: There is a plugin called WP all in one migration. Not sure if it support 3.1.2 though. Here is a link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

Edit: This plugin is free upto 500mb.

Comment: @Menno van der Krift: the OP is not asking about *migration*; they're asking about upgrading.

Comment: The plugin is called WP all in one Migration allows you to import and export WP backups. Seeing he's asking about a backup before updating Wordpress to the most recent version.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search will find the WordPress Codex on backups, which outlines many options: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Backups

But that's not the only thing to consider. It's best to do manual, incremental upgrades from 3.1 to 3.2, 3.2 to 3.5 and then to latest (from the dashboard) 4.1 to be sure the database gets upgraded properly.

Your current theme won't work well under 4.1, due to lots of changes.

So backup your database, deactivate all plugins, and switch to the default theme before upgrading.

Older versions available at [Release Archive.](http://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/) And see [Upgrading WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress)